# Uniform limit of a sequence of sign-changing functions must change sign

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, uniform-convergence

Suppose that $(w_n)$ is a sequence of sign-changing functions such that $w_n \to \varphi_1$ uniformly on the bounded smooth set $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^N$, and $w_n = 0$ on $\partial \Omega$. Is it true that $\varphi_1$ must change sign?

Motivation: in my book, $\varphi_1$ is the first eigenvalue of the Laplacian, and the authors claim that the convergence would imply a contradiction as $\varphi_1$ doesn't change sign. What I'm thinking is that the minimum of $w_n$ (which is negative) could be closer and closer to $0$, with the minimum point tending to the boundary, such that the uniform convergence still holds and therefore there is no contradiction. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

More details on $w_n$:
it solves
$$
- \Delta w_n = g_n w_n + \lambda w_n \text{ in } \Omega, \qquad w_n = 0 \text{ on } \partial \Omega
$$
with $g_n \to \lambda_1 - \lambda$, $\lambda < \lambda_1$, $\lambda_1$ the first eigenvalue of the Laplacian

Comment: No, consider $x-1/n$ as a sequence of functions $(0,1)\to\Bbb R$. The uniform limit is the strictly positive function $(0,1)\to\Bbb R$, $x\mapsto x$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but perhaps I missed an importante detail: that $w_n = 0$ on the boundary of $\Omega$. Does it change things? I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: It remains false, look at $x\cdot (1-x)\cdot (x-1/n)$ which now converges to the positive function $x^2 (1-x)$ while remaining $0$ on the boundary. Its easier to draw pictures of whats happening than write out the expressions of these functions: Here the location of the sign-change is moved over to the boundary as $n\to\infty$, so only the positive "interior" remains.